# Button does not receive click event when focus is on input element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, css-position

I have a simple form with one `input` field and one submit `button`. The `input` field has a "hint" - a small help text - that has to be shown when focus is on it.

The `input` field acts as a required field.

When the `button` is clicked, focus has to be put on the input field (this would be in the case the validation failed, which for this test is always the case).

On desktop the hint has **absolute positioning** (shows at the right of the element) and everything works as expected.

On mobile (or screens with max-width 500px), the hint has **static positioning** - the default -, to have the hint show below the input element.

**The problem is** that with static positioning the button requires two clicks for receiving the click event. I have been hours investigating this issue without success. Actually it does not matter the mobile or desktop difference: if the hint has position: static this does not work also on desktop.

This is my test HTML and a simple Javascript that handles the button click and gives focus to the input element.

```js
document
  .getElementById('submit')
  .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('first_name').focus();
  });
```

```css
.form-field {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}

.hint {
  display: none;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20em;  
  width: 15em;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fffbb8;
  border: 1px solid #ffc20d;
}

input:focus + .hint {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .hint {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">

  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="first_name">First name</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
    <div class="hint">Enter the first name</div>
  </div>    

  <div class="form-field">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

I first tried listening for clicks on the button with jQuery. I then isolated the problem by removing jQuery and the problem persists.

By just changing the `position` to *absolute* the button responds to every click on it (and the hint shows on the right as expected). When position is `static` or `unset`, the hint shows below - as expected - but the button does not receive the click when the focus is already on the input.

This issue is happening on a form with more than one field. For the sake of clarity it was reduced to a form with one field and one button.

You can see the problem live on this [on this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s251mq6e/3/). By changing the width of the results pane you can test the static positioning case.

Comment: Is `mousedown` an option, instead of `click`? It will work and give you desired behaviour.

Comment: @AidHadzic's suggestion does work. It looks like what is happening is when the hint is static and the input loses focus, the button is moved up.

Comment: It's exactly what @imvain2 says. The button "jumps" up because the hint text is removed and therefore (when statically positioned) the button is no longer pushed down by it. This means the `click` event never fires because when the user releases the mouse, the mouse is no longer over the button - a `click` event means precisely that the mouse is pressed down and then released *while over the same element*.

Comment: as for what the solution is - choose your own preference. (Or that of your users if this is for a public application.) Personally I think the hint text only appearing when focused on the input is pretty disconcerting so I would just keep it there permanently, and that would solve this issue.

Comment: Using `mousedown` instead of `click`, as suggested by @AidHadzic solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Static positioning takes place. When the screen size is less than 500 pixels when the button is pressed and hint is displayed it takes space and the location of your button changes and the document receives the keyup event, as a result of which the input is no longer focused.

Comment: one way is that you can change display:none with visibility:hidden and display:block with visibility:visible to hide hint but still take own space.